# Can Kafka handle cloud-scale load without horizontal sharding?

Tags: scalability, kafka

Per this [kadek.com article](https://www.kadeck.com/blog/how-many-partitions-do-i-need-in-apache-kafka#:%7E:text=maximum%20200%2C000%20partitions%20per%20Kafka,50%20brokers%20per%20Kafka%20cluster),

> **Kafka partition limits**
>
> There are no hard limits on the number of partitions in Kafka
> clusters. But here are a few general rules:
>
> - maximum 4000 partitions per broker (in total; distributed over many topics)
> - maximum 200,000 partitions per Kafka cluster (in total; distributed over many topics)
> - resulting in a maximum of 50 brokers per Kafka cluster
>
> This reduces downtime in case something does go wrong. But beware: It
> should not be your goal to push these limits. In many “medium data”
> applications, you don’t need any of this.

the guideline is to have 50 brokers per cluster at max.

If an application cannot do horizontal sharding for its data for some reason, does this mean that a single Kafka cluster based solution isn't suitable for cloud scale use? By cloud scale I mean pretty much an infinite number of producers and consumers.

Comment: How exactly does application data sharding relate to Kafka?

Comment: A single 50-broker cluster wouldn't possible be able to handle an infinite number of producers and consumers. Meaning, to scale further multiple clusters would be needed. Meaning, the single source of truth sitting in my kafka cluster would need to be horizontally sharded (based geography, IP address etc).